# Javascript: Best way to search for Regular Expression in an Object's keys

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let's say I have the following code to check if the words in an array are found in a dictionary and then do some sort of action if they are:

```
let dictionary = {
   aaa : 'value1',
   bbb : 'value2',
   ccc : 'value3'
}

let wordsArr = ['dfjd', 'aaa', 'Bbb', 'dfjkd']

for (let word of wordsArr) {
   if (word in dictionary) {
      console.log(word, 'is in dictionary')
   }
}
```

But now I want the if statement that checks if the word is in the dictionary to ignore case!

The obvious way I've thought of is to have a second loop, looping through `Object.keys(dictionary)` and doing a `.test()` on each key.

```
let dictionary = {
   aaa : 'value1',
   bbb : 'value2',
   ccc : 'value3'
}

let wordsArr = ['dfjd', 'aaa', 'Bbb', 'dfjkd']

for (let word of wordsArr) {
   let re = new RegExp(word, 'i');
   for (key of Object.keys(dictionary)){
      if (re.test(key)) {
      console.log(word, 'is in dictionary')
      }
   }
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this rather than looping through EVERY key in the dictionary for every word in the array. For example, using the `in` operator or the `.hasOwnProperty()` method.

Comment: You can use Map for dictionary instead  of   object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the if statement that checks if the word is in the dictionary to ignore case!

And you've chosen regex to do that case-insensitive matching, which only [causes you a second problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/66652) (e.g. to do proper escaping).

No, all you need to do is [convert the word to lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), and look for that in your dictionary of lowercase keys:

```js
const dictionary = {
   aaa : 'value1',
   bbb : 'value2',
   ccc : 'value3'
}

const wordsArr = ['dfjd', 'aaa', 'Bbb', 'dfjkd']

for (const word of wordsArr) {
   if (word.toLowerCase() in dictionary) {
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      console.log(word, 'is in dictionary')
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd not thought about regex in that way. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you can preserve your `O(1)` (i.e. fast) lookup time if you:

- Store all words in the dictionary lowercased*
- Convert the word to check `.toLowerCase()`* (like `word.toLowerCase() in dictionary`)

That way, the case information is lost, and you end up with the same string that you can use as the dictionary key.

However, if you really wanted to match keys against a regex, you'd have to iterate over all keys.

<sup>* This all will work with uppercasing too, just that lowercase is more readable when printed out</sup>